# As combine 2 ListView.ItemContainerStyle (?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm using "MahApps.Metro" and I want to add a tool tip to each ListViewItem. But I have a problem if I use "ListView.ItemContainerStyle" in the ".xaml" file, I lose metro (colors/effects). As I can combine them?

```
<ListView
...
...
...
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ToolTip>
                        ...
                        ...
                        ...
                    </ToolTip>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Thx!!!

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple. It is logical part. You just use Border for your Item and use tooltip service here. ***(ToolTipService.ToolTip="I am ItemToolTIP")***

For Exp:

```
<DataTemplate>
                        <Border ToolTipService.ToolTip="I am ItemToolTIP">
                            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Height="60" Margin="15,0,15,0"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subtitle}" Foreground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlaySecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="15,0,15,10"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: ToolTipService.ToolTip is available in every elements. So you can use any of control.